# Set last year selected with jQuery UI datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I set a range of years like this

```
$(".date").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: '1900:c-18'
});
```

That shows a year dropdown from 1900 to "18 years before today". The datepicker it set to today's day but in 1900. How can I make the years dropdown to be set on the last available year?

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/fdE2S/

Comment: set `defaultDate`. http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-yearRange

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you carefully see the datepicker, you will find it is pointing to current date

> **03/09/2013 not 03/09/1990**

*Since you have hideout the current year it is not showing up.*  ie., if you remove the the **`yearRange`** you will find it.

Therefore you need to set the year explicitly in **`defaultDate`** like this

```
defaultDate : '-18y' //Subtract 18 years from current date
```

Finally the complete code

```
var date = new Date();
$(".date").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: '1900:-18',
    defaultDate : '-18y'    
});
```

Check this in [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/APQk6/795/)

Comment: I thought the point was to restrict it to 18 years ago today? thus the reason I posted the use of `minDate` and `maxDate`? [**See the difference**](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/L7Bc7/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(".date").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    defaultDate: "-18y",
    minDate: new Date(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    maxDate: "-18y",
    yearRange: '1900:-18'
});
```

Use of Min and maxDate well restrict it so user cannot select beyond 18 years ago today. Also, using defaultDate will set the date as you requested, to 18 years ago today via the format "-18y".

## jsFiddle